# how to use encoder measurement for dc motor to control robot movement with python?

Tags: python

I have a robot car with 2 dc motor 
a dc encoder that connect to RPi 3 b and dc motor
I want to make a robot move according to number of rotation that measure by encoder . so that 
robot move and encoder start to measure 
when it reach 5 rotation, robot will stop,
Now my problem is I can't turn right or left, how to do that
I used python and RPi

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(31,GPIO.IN)


GPIO.setup(29,GPIO.IN)

GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setup(16,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setup(35,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setup(33,GPIO.OUT)


pwm=20

frequency=70000

right=GPIO.PWM(12,frequency)

left=GPIO.PWM(33,frequency)

left.start(0)

right.start(0)

def on():

    right.ChangeDutyCycle(pwm)

    left.ChangeDutyCycle(pwm)

def off():

    right.ChangeDutyCycle(0)

    left.ChangeDutyCycle(0)

prv=0

i=0

while True:

          on()  

          if(GPIO.input(31)==(1) and GPIO.input(29)==(1)):

             print"something"

             if prv==0:

                  prv=1

                  i=i+1

                  print"hole"+ str(i)+"times"

                  if i==50

                     off()

                     break     


          else:

                   print"button not pushed"

                   prv=0
```

Comment: Your entire code is `enter codhello`?

Comment: sorry I am beginner, I edited the post

Answer (score 0):

Turning left or right is a matter of turning one of the motors on instead of both (or running one side faster than the other). You could try writing the functions `turnleft()` and `turnright()` and running them in the loop (hook them to a button or something).

The function for turning left would look something like this:

```
def turnleft():
    right.ChangeDutyCycle(pwm)
    left.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
```

Comment: I know this function,,,, but my problem is when to call it inside loop ?? because loop here count the repetition  of i and i represent the hole count of wheel sensor( no of rotation) so i want to make i =zero when stop function. so that the car can rotate left and right ,, I don't know where to put it